# Can wso2 siddhi CEP accept stream of user defined objects? Can the rule be specified to access attributes of the object?

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I want to pass truck objects to my wso2 siddhi cep and evaluate a rule to raise an alarm every time truck.temperatureReading goes below 45 . Is this feasible ?

```
define stream truckStream (truck Truck) 
    from  truckStream [truck.temperatureReading  <= 45]  insert into mycallback;
```

I understand that the below is the normal way of doing it but i am specific to the above scenario.

```
define stream truckStream ( int truckid ,int temperatureReading) 
   from  truckStream [temperatureReading  <= 45]  insert into mycallback;
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently Siddhi/WSO2 CEP cannot process object, thy only support primitives.

Suho

Comment: Is this still true?